# Poor performance with ListView when displaying large images

Tags: android

I have a ListView with each item being a custom layout with multiple Views (including a large image of ~445x250, a smaller image of ~40x40, etc). While scrolling, the animation is extremely choppy.

Can someone recommend how I can improve performance?

One approach I tried was to eliminate any transparency in the images being used. This did improve it slightly, though there is still a noticeable lag when before a new item scrolls into view.

Update:
Here's the View heirarchy for the custom layout (for each item) - http://pastie.org/3333903

Comment: Post your layout for the list item.

Comment: Did you use the `convertView` and the `ViewHolder` pattern on your `getView()` method from your custom adapter?

Comment: @slukian I use convertView, but not the ViewHolder pattern. I had tried the ViewHolder pattern, but the improvement is not perceptible. I suspect the major cause of lag is the rendering of large thumbnails, which occupy ~30-40% of the screen.

Comment: @CheJami Its fairly large. >150 lines. Lemme compress it into a simpler view hierarchy, so as to give you an overview.

Comment: @CheJami Updated the post with view heirarchy.

Comment: Where do you get the large images, do you download them from the web or they are in the `/res/drawable` folder?

Comment: I download them to the SD card and load them from there.

Comment: You have at least one LinearLayout that could be removed (Line 17/18 of your pastie)

Comment: Actually, 18-21 are in a different layout XML and while <include>-ing another XML, I couldn't find any way to specify layout constraints (height/width/margins) in the <include> tag. So included them inside a LinearLayout with the required constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the layout provided, there are a few things that may cause performance issues:

- Your View Hierarchy has a depth of 4. You should make your View Hierarchy as shallow as possible. Consider using a `RelativeLayout`/`TableLayout` where possible instead of nested `LinearLayout`s.
- You have nested weights. Try to avoid having nested weighted views.
- You have a *lot* of views for a row item. Remember the purpose of a `ListView` - if your rows start becoming complex, it may be a sign to look at something else to display this information.
- A `GestureOverlayView` seems a bit heavy for a `ListView` row item. Is this necessary? Considering `ListView`s a scrollable by touch, having custom gestures on row items may be a bit confusing.

You can also try using `android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"` and the ViewHolder pattern to squeeze out a bit more performance.

If you download the latest version of ADT, it will also guide you in optimising your layouts.

Apart from layout optimisations, minimal work should be done in the `getView` method of your `ListAdapter`.

Additionally, you can use `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to take advantage of hardware in Android 3.0+.

Comment: Knocking out an entire sub-tree of the view hierarchy (lines 2-14) and moving contents of the RelativeLayout@15 outside, I am still seeing a fair deal of lag (though definitely lesser than before). This makes me feel that there is only so much to be done with layout optimizations. Maybe it makes sense to do custom drawing using SurfaceView. What do you think?

Comment: Ah, maybe you are doing too much work in `getView` on your Adapter?

Comment: I will check if I can optimize getView.

Comment: Are you decoding the `Bitmap`s there?

Comment: Load them into a cache then :)

Comment: I have a listview with a depth of five :( I really have no way to improve it unless I take some decisions that my boss wouldn't agree on. It is kind of laggy now. There are lot of views in this row item I have. There is a lot of hiding views and showing views happening. In fact I'm even changing a view's parent at times in getView depending on server's response. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic table layout instead using the List view. It will improve the performance. Dynamic table layout will adjust the large image and smaller image. It will be of help to you.

Comment: Could you provide the link for your code of dynamic table layout?